# Chrome 10.0.612 dev Websocket Issue?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

Out of some reason, the latest development version of Google Chrome has a broken version of websocket it's like it is using a different version of handshake then stable version, if anyone has any info on this I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I've not heard that Chrome 10 has switched from v76. Can you dump the handshake that the server is receiving? I'm familiar with the protocol and could tell you if the client is using a different version of the protocol.

Comment: It looks like websocket still works.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe it has something to do with the vulnerability?](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/12/websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4/)

[Could it just be a stupid bug?](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57662)

Comment: Vulnerability is impacting firefox 4 and opera, as for the bug link, it's a old bug report, chrome moved on alot after that.

Comment: I think the vulnerability is with the protocol itself, and FF4 and Op11 were just the first to disable Websockets by default.

Comment: I couldn't find any report on google chome forums or dev pages that they have in fact blocked the ws protocol.